# How do you progress past level 31? Do you have to solve the cipher?

Tags: hundreds

In the new iOS game "Hundreds", once you finish each board, you can advance to the next, either by hitting "next board" or by selecting it from the level select screen.

Except when I hit next board on level 31, it takes me... back to level 31.

I'd think it was a glitch, except that the game contains ciphers, and other mysterious artifacts that lead me to believe that there's just a puzzle I need to solve.

There IS a cipher opened on level 31 (which I have not solved), but what's confusing is that I did not have to solve the earlier ciphers to progress past those levels.

If the answer does have to do with solving the cipher, please don't post its solution without using the cipher markup.

Comment: Have you finished 1–31 or did you skip some? Level 32 opened right after 31 just fine for me.

Comment: @sean, <sigh>. I was pretty sure I'd done them all, but... see below. Appreciate the question!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this is embarrassing.  It looks like I hadn't completed all the boards prior to level 31, but had instead somehow unknowingly skipped some.

This is partially due to the slightly confusing convention of showing three different board status levels:

- A small dot means you haven't finished it
- A large dot means you have finished it
- A large RED dot means you have finished it, *and* it has a cipher

I don't think it indicates one way or another if the cipher has been solved; my solved and unsolved ones look the same.

I'm still not 100% clear on when you can and can't advance; my best guess is that you can't advance past a cipher board until you've completed all the prior boards, but you can jump ahead as long as you don't pass a cipher.  That's pure speculation based on the fact that I was able to somehow get to level 31 without finishing a number of prior levels, but was not able to pass level 31 until I beat it.